# Cypher: Create relationships between nodes based on a common property key id

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm brand new to Cypher (and Stackoverflow) and am having trouble creating relationships between nodes based on share property keys.

I would like to do something like this:

```
MATCH (a:Person)-->()<--(b:Country)
WHERE HAS (a.id) AND HAS (b.id) AND a.id=b.id
CREATE (a)-[:LIVES]->(b);
```

to create a relationship between Country node and Person nodes where they share the same id.

The above creates no errors when run but doesn't create any relationships either and I know that the ids should match.

Many thanks!!

EDIT:

I think I know what is going wrong - I'm asking to match nodes that have a relationship to eachother but no relationships are set up yet hence 0 results. I have now tried:

```
MATCH (a:Person),
(b:Country)
WHERE HAS (a.id) AND HAS (b.id) AND a.id=b.id
CREATE (a)-[:LIVES]->(b);
```

and the query is running. It's a big data set so might take a while......

Comment: try to add some indexes on the keys you are matching, that will speed up the process a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That worked. Had to reduce the size of my data set (down from 64k nodes) as Neo4j was taking way too long to process but once I had a smaller set it worked fine.

Comment: Note for future googlers, `apoc.periodic.iterate()` using the APOC Procedures library is the current means to do batch processing like this without having to reduce your dataset.

Answer (score 3):

One minor addition for future Googlers.

per the help [files](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/where/#property-existence-checking) as of version 3.4

> The has() function has been superseded by exists() and has been removed.

The new code should read

```
MATCH (a:Person),
(b:Country)
WHERE EXISTS (a.id) AND EXISTS (b.id) AND a.id=b.id
CREATE (a)-[:LIVES]->(b);
```